# How to display data into gridview depending on the data provided?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm creating a class schedule viewer that's populating data from the database. I'm using gridview but the way that I've got it is that it just displays each cell in one singlular large column. I want the format of

```
     9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
```

Mon

Tues

Wed

Thurs

Fri

This is how my data is formatted for one cell:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" ShowHeader="false" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table style="border: 1px solid #A55129; background-color: #FFF7E7">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 200px">
                            <table>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>Class Code:</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblcode"
                                            runat="server"
                                            Text='<%#Eval("classCode") %>'>
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>Day:</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblday"
                                            runat="server"
                                            Text='<%#Eval("day") %>'>
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>Start Period:</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblstart"
                                            runat="server"
                                            Text='<%#Eval("periodStart") %>'>
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>End Period:</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblend"
                                            runat="server"
                                            Text='<%#Eval("periodEnd") %>'>
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>Teacher:</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblteacher"
                                            runat="server"
                                            Text='<%#Eval("teacherName") %>'>
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The above code displays one set of data from the database. But I have hundreds of these so you can imagine that the total format is one very long single column.

Can someone suggest how I can get gridview to display my suggested format and with the data in their respective cells e.g. Geography on Monday, starting at 9, ending at 11 will show up along the Monday row, over the 9 and 10 columns?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I am not sure if `GridView` is the best (or a good) candidate for such a task. I would go with Ajax & Jquery oriented solution but not sure how comfortable you are with them. Here are several ASP.NET projects that might give you an idea:

http://code.daypilot.org/65101/timetable-tutorial-asp-net-c-vb-net

http://code.daypilot.org/34377/shift-scheduling-tutorial-asp-net-sql-server-c-vb-net